# Load External Template into Toolbar Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

The goal is to have an external template loaded into a toolbar of a Kendo UI grid. I would prefer not to have any script directly in a the view itself (as seen in the example on the Kendo site). I've been messing around with $.get but have not been completely successful. What would be the best way to assign the template to the toolbar below?

Kendo Version 2012.3.1114, Visual Studio 2012

Function call in a script that sets the grid settings:

```
    var configureGrid = function() {
        var grid = $('#allItemsGrid').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: 'json',
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "api/GridApi/GetAll",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields { {
                            MusicItemId: { type: "integer" },
                            Artist: { type: "string" },
                            Title: { type: "string" },
                            Genre: { type: "string" },
                            Format: { type: "string" },
                            Notes: { type: "string" },
                            Country: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 5
            },
            toolbar: // load external template????
            sortable: true,
            pageable: { pageSizes: [5, 10, 15] },
            columns: gridCols.GridColumns
        });
```

And this is a template I have in a Tmpl folder right off the root of the MVC project:

```
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="tmplTarget">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <label class="category-label" for="category">Show By Genre:</label>
            <input type="search" id="category"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <label class="category-label" for="category">Show By Format:</label>
            <input type="search" id="category2"></input>
        </div>
        <a class="k-button" id="searchCriteria" href="\\\#" onclick="test_fn()">Search</a>
    </script>
```

Per Ryan's request. This code below is a re-work, just to see if I could get things working based off the kendo documentation. The code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html/>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>The Grid</title>
            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/templateLoader.js"></script>
            <link href="~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            templateLoader.loadExtTemplate("@Url.Content("~/Tmpl/Test.tmpl.html")");

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var _itemTemplate;
                $(document).bind("TEMPLATE_LOADED", function (e, path) {
                    console.log('Templates loaded');

                    _itemTemplate = kendo.template($('#template').html(), { useWithBlock: false });

            });
            $('#allItemsGrid').kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: 'json',
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "", // left blank, not concerned with pulling data back for now
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: 'GET',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                MusicItemId: { type: "integer" },
                                Artist: { type: "string" },
                                Title: { type: "string" },
                                Genre: { type: "string" },
                                Format: { type: "string" },
                                Notes: { type: "string" },
                                Country: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 5
                },
                toolbar: [{ name: 'customTemplate', template: _itemTemplate }],
                sortable: true,
                pageable: { pageSizes: [5, 10, 15] },  // page size using pager
                columns: [
                { field: "Artist", title: "Aritst" },
                { field: "Title", title: "Title" },
                { field: "Genre", title: "Genre" },
                { field: "Format", title: "Format" },
                { field: "Notes", title: "Notes" },
                { field: "Country", title: "Country" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style scoped="scoped">
        #grid .k-toolbar {
            min-height: 27px;
        }
        .category-label {
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding-right: .5em;
            float: left;
        }
        #category {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .toolbar {
            float: right;
            margin-right: .8em;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="allContainer">
            <div id="allItemsGrid"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the templateLoader.js file:

```
    var templateLoader = (function($, host) {
        return {
            loadExtTemplate: function(path) {
                var tmplLoader = $.get(path)
                    .success(function(result) {
                        $('body').append(result);
                    })
                    .error(function(result) {
                        alert("Error loading template...");
                });

                tmplLoader.complete(function() {
                    $(host).trigger("TEMPLATE_LOADED", [path]);
                });
            }
        };
    })(jQuery, document);
```

The template is the same as posted above. Obviously this won't work because it is appending the results to the body of the document. What I need is the results appended to the template in the grid toolbar. It is successful in pulling down the template as verified by watching the network traffic.

Comment: Have you seen the KendoUI docs that cover this? [How To: Load Templates from External Files](http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/load-templates-external-files)

Comment: Hi ryan, oh yeah I have seen that. I have been playing around with it. I tried assigning the template to the toolbar in the grid as such: toolbar: [{ name: 'customTemplate', template: _itemTemplate }] and it just renders a button with the text 'customTemplate' on the grid.

Comment: You have to setup a template loader like they did. It's not included. Can you post your code with that loader call in it, or your loader code if you used something other than their example.